# PySpark Wait to finish in notebook (Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

Currently, I'm having a few issues with having a spark dataframe (autoloader) in one cell that may take a few moments to write data. Then, in the following cell, the code references the work done by the first table. However, if the entire notebook is run (particularly, as a Job) due to the distributed nature of spark, the second cell runs before the first cell is fully completed. How can I have the second cell await the finish of the writeStream without putting them in separate notebooks.

Example:

Cell1

```
autoload = pysparkDF.writeStream.format('delta')....table('TABLE1')
```

Cell2

```
df = spark.sql('select count(*) from TABLE1')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `awaitTermination` function to wait until stream processing is finished (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#managing-streaming-queries)). Like this:

- cell 1

```py
autoload = pysparkDF.writeStream.format('delta')....table('TABLE1')
autoload.awaitTermination()
```

- cell 2

```py
df = spark.sql('select count(*) from TABLE1')
```

although it could be read easier & harder to make mistake with something like this:

```py
df = spark.read.table('TABLE1').count()
```

Update:  To wait for multiple streams:

```py
while len(spark.streams.active) > 0:
  spark.streams.resetTerminated() # Otherwise awaitAnyTermination() will return immediately after first stream has terminated
  spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will help for single stream. How to wait if there are multiple streams that are running. Need to wait for all streams to complete.

Comment: wait for multiple streams, is that achieved by any way?